# C: Segmentation Fault(Core dumped) while finding function names

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, structure

I'd like to write a C code to find all the functions in a C file and print the corresponding function names.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 1024
void ffname(char *line)
{
    int i=1,j=0;
    char *dt; 
    char *name;
    strtok(line,"("); 
    dt = strchr(line,' '); 
    if(dt[i] == '*')
        i++;
    while(dt[i] != '\0')
    {
        name[j]=dt[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    name[j] ='\0';
    printf("Function name is: %s\n", name);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Give the filename \n");
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    int i, lines =0, funlines =0,count =0, fn =0, flag =0;
    char c[100],b[100];
    FILE *fd;
    fd = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while(fgets(c,SIZE,fd))
    {   
        lines++;
        i=0;
        for(i=0;i<strlen(c);i++)
        {
            while( c[i] =='\t' || c[i] == ' ')
            {
                i++;
            }
            if( c[i] == '{')
            {
                count++;
                if(flag)
                {
                    funlines++;
                }
                if(count == 1)
                {
                    fn++;
                    printf("Function %d is Started..............\n", fn); 
                    flag = 1;
                    ffname(b);
                }
                break;
            }
            else if( c[i] == '}')
            {
                count--;
                if(!count)
                { 
                    flag = 0;
                    printf("No of lines in the function %d is: %d\n", fn, funlines);
                    printf("Function %d is finished..........\n", fn);
                    funlines = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    funlines++;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if(flag)
            {
                funlines++;
                break;
            }
        }
        strcpy(b,c);
    }
    printf("Total no of fucnion%d\n",fn);
    printf("Total no of lines%d\n",lines);
    return 0;
}
```

When I give the following C file as input,

```
#include<stdio.h>
void add()
{
    int a=5,b=7;
    printf("Addition is:%d\n", a+b);
}
void sub()
{
    int a=20,b=8;
    printf("Subtraction is:%d\n", a-b);
}
void main()
{   
    char *name="dhahira dhasneem";
    char *line;
    line=strchr(name,' ');
    printf("Line:%s\n",line);
    printf("Name:%s\n",name);
    add();
    sub();
}
```

I get the following output.

```
Function 1 is Started..............
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I use `valgrind`, but I don't know how to identify error with that. Please guide me. Thank you.

**Update:**

I got the output, when I used suggested answer. After that, I'd like to extend my previous code for storing the details of function(function name and function depth) into a Structure. I was getting output, when I used to store function details for simple program. But I'm getting the following output for my program, when I run this in`gdb`.

```
(gdb) b 87
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804885e: file fun_printstruct.c, line 87.
(gdb) r dat.c
Starting program: /home/dhahira/dhas/Project/a.out dat.c
Function 1 is Started..............

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080485d4 in ffname (line=0xbfffe71c "/*struct *dhahira", name=0x0)
    at fun_printstruct.c:21
21          name[j]=dt[i];
(gdb) s

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

My code is:(extended for storing function details into structure)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 1024
void ffname(char *line)
{
    int i=1,j=0;
    char *dt; 
    char name[SIZE];
    strtok(line,"("); 
    dt = strchr(line,' '); 
    if(dt[i] == '*')
        i++;
    while(dt[i] != '\0')
    {
        name[j]=dt[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    name[j] ='\0';
    printf("Function name is: %s\n", name);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Give the filename \n");
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    int i, lines =0, funlines =0,count =0, fn =0, flag =0, fg=0,size=0,emptyflag=0,commandflag=0;
    char c[SIZE],b[SIZE],st[SIZE],d[SIZE];
    int command[]={};
    FILE *fd;
    fd = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while(fgets(c,SIZE,fd))
    {
        emptyflag=0;    
        lines++;
        for(i=0;i<(sizeof(command)/4);i++)
        {
            if(lines == command[i])
            {
                commandflag=1;
                break;
            }   
        }
        strcpy(st,c);
        strtok(st," ");
        size = strlen(c);
        if(size == 1 && (strcmp(c,"\n"))== 0)
            emptyflag=1;
        if( !strcmp(st,"struct")) 
            fg=1;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(commandflag)
            {
                break;
            }   
            while( c[i] =='\t' || c[i] == ' ')
            {
                i++;
            }
            if( c[i] == '{')
            {
                count++;
                if(flag)
                {
                    if(!emptyflag)
                        funlines++;
                    else
                        emptyflag=0;
                }
                if(count ==1 && fg ==1)
                {
                    if(b[strlen(b)-2] == ')')
                    {
                        fn++;
                        printf("Function %d is Started..............\n", fn); 
                        flag = 1;
                        ffname(b);
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        count--;
                    }   
                }
                else if(count == 1)
                {
                    fn++;
                    printf("Function %d is Started..............\n", fn); 
                    flag = 1;
                    ffname(b);
                }
                break;
            }
            else if( c[i] == '}')
            {
                count--;
                if(count ==0 && fg ==1)
                { 
                    flag = 0;
                    printf("No of lines in the function %d is: %d\n", fn, funlines);
                    printf("Function %d is finished..........\n", fn);
                    funlines = 0;
                    fg=0;
                }
                else if(count ==0)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    printf("No of lines in the function %d is: %d\n", fn, funlines);
                    printf("Function %d is finished..........\n", fn);
                    funlines = 0;
                }
                else if(count == -1)
                {
                    count=0;
                    fg=0;
                }
                else 
                {
                    if(!emptyflag)
                        funlines++;
                    else
                        emptyflag=0;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if(flag ==1 && fg==1)
            {
                if(!emptyflag)
                    funlines++;
                else
                    emptyflag=0;
                break;
            }
            else if(flag)
            {
                if(!emptyflag)
                    funlines++;
                else
                    emptyflag=0;
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        if(commandflag == 1)
            commandflag = 0;
        else
            strcpy(b,c);
    }
    printf("Total no of fucnion%d\n",fn);
    printf("Total no of lines%d\n",lines);
    return 0;
}
```

Please guide me to overcome from this problem.

Is this problem coming because of extending the code?(I can get the correct output separately.)

Comment: Start by using GDB, it will show you what line it is seg faulting on.

Comment: And get the habit to compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and to improve your code till no warnings are given. Then Use `gdb` and `valgrind` to debug your program.

Comment: Also, `char *name = "foo";` is **wrong,** use `char name[] = "foo";` or `const char *name = "foo";` instead.

Comment: I haven't followed through the logic, but with: `char c[100],b[100];` you probably shouldn't have: `while(fgets(c,SIZE,fd))`, where `SIZE` is defined as `(1024)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring `SIZE` as 1024, and then reading into an array of length 100:

```
#define SIZE 1024
// ... snip ....
    char c[100],b[100];
    FILE *fd;
    fd = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while(fgets(c,SIZE,fd))
```

This means you're writing well past the bounds of your array, onto the rest of your stack, and causing corruption. In this case, that probably doesn't actually happen because your lines in your input file are all under 100 characters, but it could if someone passed in a file with long lines.

This should be either

```
    char c[SIZE],b[SIZE];
```

or use `sizof()` in the `fgets()` call:

```
fgets(c,sizeof(c),fd)
```

As others have pointed out, it's best if you turn on all available warnings; this will help you catch errors more quickly. In GCC or Clang, I would recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`; this will enable all of the common warnings, and cause warnings to be treated as errors so you cannot ignore them. If I run that on your code, I also get the following warnings:

```
sf.c:16:9: error: variable 'name' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
        name[j]=dt[i];
        ^~~~
sf.c:9:15: note: initialize the variable 'name' to silence this warning
    char *name;
              ^
               = NULL
sf.c:40:18: error: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long') [-Werror,-Wsign-compare]
        for(i=0;i<strlen(c);i++)
                ~^~~~~~~~~~
```

The second isn't a serious problem, just cast it or declare `i` unsigned; the first you should fix. You need to allocate a buffer for name, either on the stack (`char name[SIZE];` or similar), or dynamically (`char *name = malloc(strlen(line));`, or something like that). As it is, `name` is an uninitialized pointer; it could point anywhere in memory, and once you try dereferencing it by storing something in `name[j]`, you are writing to an invalid memory region and getting a segfault.

Finally, once you've fixed those problems, if you have further problems, I'd recommend running it under a debugger, and see where the problems occur. If you're using an IDE, it probably has a debugger interface built in; if not, compile with `-g`, and run `gdb executable arguments`.

Comment: Sir, I used both way u suggested, till now I'm getting the same error as I mentioned above.

Comment: @Dhas I've expanded my answer. The first bug I mentioned still needs to be fixed, but it wouldn't actually crash your program without input lines longer than 100 characters. I realized that you have another, more serious bug: you never initialize `name` in `ffname`, which means you trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: it works, if i use "char name[SIZE];". thank you for your guidance Sir.

Comment: Sir, I've updated my question above. Please consider my question and give me your suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Dhas A few suggestions. For one, it doesn't look like the code you pasted in there corresponds to the error you got. The error says you have `name[j]=dt[i];` on line 21, but you have `printf("Function name is: %s\n", name);` on line 21. Make sure you are actually looking at the same code you're debugging. For another, it's best to ask a new question on StackOverflow; this question is different than the first you asked, which I already answered.

Comment: @Dhas And finally, when asking a question, it's best to reduce your code down as much as possible. The more code there is in the question, the harder it will be to find the bug in it. If you get rid of everything extraneous, and still have a short example that demonstrates your problem, it might even help you find it (as you will be looking only at a few lines of code); if not, it will make it a lot easier for other people to focus on that one problem. See http://sscce.org/ for details.

Comment: Thank u Sir, I put last question in separate question. but that is not accepted. Thats why, I have updated here. And I will get an output, when i used it in a simple program, but i didn't get when i updated it in already written code. To find out the exact problem, I am posting full of my code Sir.

Comment: @Dhas What do you mean "that is not accepted"? You asked another question, and someone answered it for you. You said in the other question "Yes Sir, Now it's working Properly. Thank you for your guidance." Did something change since you said that? You also didn't address my comment about the code not being the same as the one you are debugging. In the debugger, it gives an error about `name[j]=dt[i];` on line 21, but you don't have that line on line 21 in the code you pasted above. I cannot help you if I can't see the actual code you are running when you get the error.